# Bootstrap datetimepicker add 1 day to mindate

Tags: datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap datetimepicker, how do I add one day in datetimepicker bootstrap `minDate`?

I want to filter the `minDate` for more 1 day. For example my `checkIn` datetimepicker is 02/16/18 then the the date to 02/16/18 is disabled in `checkOut` datetimepicker.

```html
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#CheckIn').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        });
        $('#CheckOut').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,//Important! See issue #1075
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        });

        $("#CheckIn").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#CheckOut').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });

        $("#CheckOut").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#CheckIn').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the docs says, [`dp.change`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange):

> Fired when the date is changed.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> e = {
>   date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
>   oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null
> }
> ```

since `e.date` is a moment object you can use [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) method.

Here a live example:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#CheckIn').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  });
  $('#CheckOut').datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,//Important! See issue #1075
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  });

  $("#CheckIn").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    if( e.date ){
      e.date.add(1, 'day');
    }
    $('#CheckOut').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });

  $("#CheckOut").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#CheckIn').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-sm-6'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id="CheckIn">
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='col-sm-6'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id="CheckOut">
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great help. It works for me too. But I need to add 3 days. if anyone need my code then use it.

```js
        $(function (){
        $('#datetimepicker1_1').datetimepicker({
        minDate: new Date(),
        date: new Date()
        });
        var endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+4);
        $('#datetimepicker2_1').datetimepicker({
        minDate:endDate,
        date: endDate
        });
        $("#datetimepicker1_1").on("dp.change", function (e){
        if (e.date){
        e.date.add(4,'day');
        }
       $('#datetimepicker2_1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>



    <input onkeyup="first_step_val()" maxlength="100" id='datetimepicker1_1'  type="text" name="start_date" required="required" class="form-control" />

    <input onkeyup="first_step_val()" maxlength="100" type="text" id='datetimepicker2_1' name="end_date" required="required" class="form-control"  />
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}


why I am facing this error. :(