# DateTimePicker - Add days in a given period

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datetimepicker

Good Morning.
I found this code that serves my purpose:

```
$(function () {
  $('#CheckIn').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  });
  $('#CheckOut').datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,//Important! See issue #1075
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  });

  $("#CheckIn").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    if( e.date ){
      e.date.add(1, 'day');
    }
    $('#CheckOut').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });

  $("#CheckOut").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#CheckIn').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
  });

});
```

Link: [Bootstrap datetimepicker add 1 day to mindate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815270/bootstrap-datetimepicker-add-1-day-to-mindate#)

But I need to make some adjustments. I need to add days in certain periods.
I tried this, but without success:

```
$(function () { 
  $('#CheckIn').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  });
  $('#CheckOut').datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,//Important! See issue #1075
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  });

  $("#CheckIn").on("dp.change", function (e) {

        if(( e.date >= new Date(2018, 8, 01) && ( e.date <= new Date(2018, 8, 10)){
          e.date.add(3, 'day');
        }
        if(( e.date >= new Date(2018, 9, 01) && ( e.date <= new Date(2018, 9, 10)){
          e.date.add(5, 'day');
        }

  $('#CheckOut').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });

  $("#CheckOut").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#CheckIn').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
  });

});
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "wuthout success", do you mean an error or nothing happens?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `new Date(yyyy, mm, dd)` to create date, mm (month) is 0 based. i.e. 0 is January and 11 is December.

So, `new Date(2018, 8, 01)` will create date Sept 1, 2018.

Change your code to 0 based month and it worked. Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/11721/

Following is the syntax:

```
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

> **monthIndex**
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to
>   11 for December.

For more details check this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date